# In openGL. How do you copy part of a texture to another texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am trying to create a blank (white with no alpha) texture where I can load other textures and write part of them.   I tried just having to get a portion of the texture, and using glTexSubImage2D to put it there it doesn't seem to work right. Anyone have any idea how to do this? What am i doing wrong?

```
int sourceTextWidth;
int sourceTextHeight;
int sourceFormat;
int formatOffset = 0;

//bind the texture
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID );

//get its params
glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_COMPONENTS, &sourceFormat);
glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &sourceTextWidth);
glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, &sourceTextHeight);
switch (sourceFormat)
{
    case GL_RGB:
    {
        formatOffset = 3;
    }
    break;
    case GL_RGBA:
    {
        formatOffset = 4;
    }
    break;
}
if (formatOffset == 0)
{
    return false;
}


unsigned char * sourceData = (unsigned char *)malloc(sourceTextWidth * sourceTextHeight * formatOffset);

glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sourceData);

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_currentTextureId );

unsigned char * destData = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * height * 3);



glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sourceData);

for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{       
memcpy(&destData[(i * width * 3) ], &sourceData[((i + y) * sourceTextWidth * 3) + (x * 3)], width * 3);
}
//glDeleteTextures (1, m_currentTextureId);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_currentTextureId );

glTexSubImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, destData );
free(destData);
free(sourceData);
```

Comment: Try using glCopyTexSubImage2D for this: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCopyTexSubImage2D.xml

Comment: However, with glCopyTexSubImage2D, you'll need to make sure you're reading from the texture, not the backbuffer, using glFramebufferTexture2D I believe.

Comment: I answered this question for GPU internal copy with OpenGL, but StackOverflow is becoming stupid since my very precise question was marked duplicate of a lousy unprecise one, and another high ranked user even changed my question to make no sense any more. Now I wish everybody lots of fun finding the solution to the problem by themselves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy texture1 to texture2 efficiently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100308/how-to-copy-texture1-to-texture2-efficiently)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have access to [OpenGL 4.3 or the ARB_copy_image extension](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_copy) (or its older cousin, NV_copy_image), then you can [use `glCopyImageSubData`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glCopyImageSubData).

Otherwise, you could use FBO blitting. You attach the source texture to [an FBO](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object), attach the destination texture to an FBO (possibly the same one, but if so, then obviously not to the same attachment point), set the [read buffers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Read_color_buffer) and [draw buffers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Draw_color_buffers) for the FBOs to read from the source attachment and draw to the destination attachment, and then [blit from one framebuffer to the other](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Blitting).

The trick you're trying to do doesn't work, BTW, because you never allocated *storage* for your new texture. `glTexSubImage` *cannot be called* for an image in a texture unless [storage for that image](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage) has been allocated. This can be by a [call to `glTexImage` or one of a number of other functions.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Mutable_storage) The "SubImage" functions are all for uploading to existing storage, not for creating new storage.

Comment: Thank you! I had a little issues getting it working, but it's working and efficient.