# WebGL copy texture framebuffer to texture framebuffer?

Tags: opengl-es, rendering, webgl, webgl-extensions

I am trying to copy a texture framebuffer to another one in WebGL, and so far it just gives an black screen. I am able to render in the texture framebuffer without problems.

Here is the code I thought that would work (it currently works on iOS):

```
// bind source fbo while we remember current fbo
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &current_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, src_framebuffer);

// setup source fbo attachments
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, src_handle, 0);
//glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0); <- commented out because it is not available in WebGL

// bind destination fbo
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
glBindTexture(dest_target, dest_handle);

// copy from source to dest
glCopyTexImage2D(dest_target, 0, dest_format, 0, 0, dest_width, dest_height, 0);

// set back original fbo
//glReadBuffer(GL_NONE); 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, current_fbo);
```

WebGL doesn't support glReadBuffer so I can't specify it, however with the WEBGL_draw_buffers extension it support multiple render targets so we can set attachments no problem (hence why the render to texture framebuffer work flawless).

I realize that since I can't specify the read buffer, perhaps this technique just can't work? Any thoughts or work-arounds?

Comment: I'm confused. The code above is OpenGL not WebGL

Comment: @gman Yes, it is because I am compiling my code through Emscripten, so it still ends up being WebGL after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use WebGL 2.0, you can simply do:

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, src);
gl.bindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, dst);
gl.blitFramebuffer(src_left, src_bottom, src_right, src_top, 0, 0, dst_width, dst_height, mask, GL_NEAREST);
```

Otherwise I suppose it is right to use `gl.copyTexImage2D`. A more detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100308/how-to-copy-texture1-to-texture2-efficiently).

Answer (score 1):

CopyTexImage2D works just fine. Here's 2 conformance tests

https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/textures/copy-tex-image-2d-formats.html?webglVersion=1

https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/textures/copy-tex-image-and-sub-image-2d.html?webglVersion=1

Have you checked the JavaScript console for errors? You're only copying level 0 which means you either need to set your filtering correctly or you need to generate mips. The JavaScript console would likely contain error messages about the texture being unrenderable

Comment: STUPID SO won't let me post a jsfiddle link without code but the code is irrelevant to the point so here's a link http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/rs21sr46/

Comment: I'm not sure this link provides an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Let me try to explain again: I'm trying to read from a renderable texture framebuffer and copy it into another renderable texture framebuffer. Usually the code I provided works just fine on iOS. But since we can't specify the read buffer in WebGL, what is the alternative route?

Comment: How about render to destination framebuffer with sampling from source texture/framebuffer. glCopyTexImage2D is likely implement like that in the drive code anyway.